# Problem in implementing SLAM in ROS

Tags: ros, navigation, 3d-slam, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know the algorithms of the SLAM but I want to implement my own code without using gmapping I know how SLAM is implemented but don't know how to integrate it with ROS. Is their any guide I also know how to publish nodes in Ros but what I have to do to create a map from laser data without using gmapping or any ROS commands. Can anyone help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262191/problem-in-implementing-slam-in-ros/) by [Dhagash Desai](https://answers.ros.org/users/26869/dhagash-desai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-05-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know, there are no guides. I suggest you to have a look at gmapping, amcl and mapserver nodes.

In practice you have to implement the following things (presuming that you are going to work with most recent graph-slam theories)

- a node that listen to odom and scan topics. When the distance traveled overcomes a certain threshold you add a node to your topological map. A laser scan has to be attached to each node. Then, each time you add a new node you can perform least squares adjustment, loop closure and similar stuffs.
- a node that given the graph (and so the last optimized node) correct the robot position. Your tf tree has to be something like this: map -> odom -> base_link . The robot moves with respect to the odom frame, so to correct drift you have to publish a map to odom transform.
- a node that given the graph, creates the map as an occupancy grid. This can be done again using the graph: given the scan associated to nodes, you can elaborate the map. For example, considering a single scan, assume that the first laser ray reaches distance D, so you know that the cells from the robot pose until D, along the ray direction, will be free; the cell at D will be an obstacle; the cells behind D will remain unknown. Obviously you have to integrate together the information coming from all the scans, because maybe a successive scan could see the same obstacle at distance D+1 and so on.... So you have to assign to each cell a probability of being occupied or not, depending on how many rays go beyond it and on how many stops at it.

I hope that this can clarify your ideas.

---

Originally posted by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) with karma: 1322 on 2017-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dhagash Desai](https://answers.ros.org/users/26869/dhagash-desai/) on 2017-05-21**:
Thanks this will surely help can u give your email id if I get stuck some where I can mail you. Thanks in advance